# Using this operator to get a variable in a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, this

When the 'this' operator is used to reference a variable in the current object is that included in the constructor? For example...

```
public class Mechanics {

    public Mechanics() {
      int x = 1;

    }

   public int returnX(){
    return this.x;
 {

}
```

As the constructor is called when the object is created will the 'this' operator return the x in the constructor or only a variable that is outside?

Thanks

Comment: You should read up on variable scope.

Comment: The scope of `x` is restricted to the constructor. So no, you won't be able to reference it.

Comment: Moreover, variables and data members are completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not valid and won't compile. `x` as defined in the constructor is *local to the constructor only*. It is not a field of the `Mechanics` class. To be able to use `x` somewhere else, you need to declare it as a field of the class:

```
public class Mechanics {

    private int x;

    public Mechanics() {
        this.x = 1; //initialize x in the constructor

    }         

    public int returnX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

This is just as well, because with the behavior that you are expecting, any local variable you declare inside any member method of a class (including the constructor) would turn into a field of the owning class. This is a recipe for anarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The scope the variable `x` is restricted to the constructor.

If you want access to `x` in `returnX` you could do so:

```
public class Mechanics {

     private int x;

    public Mechanics() {
       this.x =1;

    }

   public int returnX(){
    return this.x;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

X is local variable inside constructor, and it doesn't exist after constructor finished it's work. Your code will not compile.

"this" is just a reference to object of this class. Is it possible to get value of some local variable inside other method? No, no matter how You try.
You need class field, that is visible to all methods.